# Is there such a thing as a resistive bus bar to substitute many resistors?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, current-limiting, semiconductors

I find myself in the position to design Burn-In racks for a capacitor manufacturing company. I am trying to replace the multitude of resistors on boards that limit the current and isolate each capacitor enduring the burn in conditioning process. This becomes very bulky so I have been trying to compress the rack and keep it cheap at the same time. So if you laid a semi-conductive bus bar on top of a copper bus bar you could then tap off of the semi conductor and connect it to the capacitor to limit the current. That's my theory at least, so is there such a thing and is it possible to achieve a consistent resistance around 5-10kohms?

Comment: You can get tiny surface mount packages containing multiple resistors - what sort of current do they need to pass?

Comment: It would need to withstand an instant discharge of 1mF from 1kVDC. These are also inside of 125 degree Celsius ovens. The point of the resistors is to protect the other capacitors from clearings that occur in the film and cause all the others to discharge into that one clearing.

Answer (score 5):

Unless I misunderstand, your question brings to mind [these sort of things](http://darcy.rsgc.on.ca/ACES/Datasheets/Bourns_ResistorNetworks.pdf)

[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks like the very thing... although I would look very carefully at why the original design does not use resistor networks - they've been around for 25+ years so there may be some ancient wisdom at play in the design.

Comment: That would definitely be a good idea, but I don't know if they would be able to stand up to the circumstances since they will be in 125 degree Celsius ovens at varying voltages from 100 to 2000 VDC. We typically use 10 watt 5kohm resistors.